# Some Plotly chart events dont' work properly in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, plotly.js

I am using ploty.js with Angular to build some charts, but some of the events are not triggering. I am using this wrapper: 
https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js
and the 'selected' event which corresponds to 'plotly_selected' doesn't work. Here is my code:

View:

```
<plotly-plot [data]="myData" [layout]="myLayout" (selected)="selected($event)" (hover)="hover($event)"></plotly-plot>
```

Component:

```
selected = (e) => {
    console.log('Selected e is: ', e);
}

hover(event: any): void {
    console.log(event);
}
```

'hover' works fine, but 'selected' never gets called.

I tried also to use Vanilla JS:

View:

```
<div class="graph-item" #graphBox id="graphBox">
```

Component:

```
// this works
(document.getElementById('graphBox') as any).on('plotly_hover', function(data){
    console.log('data is: ', data);
});

// this doesn't work
(document.getElementById('graphBox') as any).on('plotly_selected', function(data){
    console.log('data is: ', data);
});
```

Is there another way to use Plotly with Angular? I need to work with the Plotly events to synchronize multiple charts. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I see the same problem and opened an issue here: https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/issues/21

Comment: plotly_selected works for me. However, I wait to hook events until after creating the chart with Plotly.newPlot (or Plotly.react). So try your vanilla test but delay until after chart creation.